# How to drop a value in a column with a specific condition?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements

I am new to pandas and I want to filter my column c (that is much longer on my df). I just need to drop the several E99 that are in column b.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [E99, 08A, 13B], [7, 8, 9]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

This is my dataframe df:

```
   a  b    c
0  1  E99  3
1  4  08A  6
2  7  13B  9
....
```

I tried this :

```
df = df[df["b"] != "E99"]
```

but it just doesn't work, with this I have:

```
df
   a  b  c
0  1  0  3
1  4  1  6
2  7  2  9
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please mention what do you want your E99 to replace with? For example 0 or NaN?

Comment: This syntax should do the job - `df.loc[df['b'] == 'E99', ['b']] = 'value_to_be_replaced'`